# The most server-friendly way of recording user stats into mySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck with a situation, where I require to record user's statistics (i.e. record how many pages did the user view). Due to limited resources and high amount of views I can't afford to record stats directly to the database.

My version of the solution was to save stats to the session and then once in every 10 minutes the stats will be recorded to the database. But what happens if user closes the browser in between this 10 minute "checkpoints"? Is there a way PHP script could check the session without user being online?

Comment: Must be very high traffic ;) Never the less. Store the data into a file with the name of the session id. Use a cronjob when traffic is low to crawl all these files and write them to the db.

Comment: Very high traffic indeed! Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Custom session handlers](http://php.net/manual/ro/session.customhandler.php). By implementing [SessionHandlerInterface](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) class you can change default behaviour of session *destroy* and *close* functions. So you will be able to save your data whenever session is closed or destroyed.

Comment: Do this work in the scenario the user close his browser ?

Comment: @Aurel it changes the way sessions are handled, so it doesn't depend on browser being opened or closed. IMHO.

Comment: @Aurel It really does not depend on browser, because sessions are completely managed by server. You must take care of all used methods as `gc` which may delete session data that are not processed (saved counters in this case), because calling `gc` method does not call `destroy` on expired sessions.

Comment: @Peky Indeed, thanks for the tips, I didn't know about session gc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a nosql DB in-memory like Redis for his speed to record stats on each views and then periodically aggregate this data into a mysql table.